# "soft lockup - CPU# 0 stuck for " after xen install on Ubuntu Server

Tags: xen

I finally managed to install xen-hypervisor-amd64 on an Ubuntu 15.04 Server
and I rebooted fine, but after a few minutes after a restart, the console starts outputting these messages
`soft lockup - CPU# 0 stuck for 22s!`
and 
`rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU { 0} (t= ...)`
with `t` increasing slowly with each new message.

I read somewhere on this forum to make a change in virtmanager:
'change virtio to SATA'

Does this apply for Xen as well ?
How can I change this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trick solved the soft lockup problem for me:

```
apt-get install intel-microcode microcode.ctl
```

[From here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1685278.html)